# Orchard 1.6 Pagination?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Orchard version is 1.6.

I have created a projection to list my book items. For example, books total number is 10. In projeciton setting page, **Items to display is set to 3**. and **Show pager option is enabled**. save and refresh webpage, actually pager is enabled with **Older and Newer** paginatin link.

But my pagination expect is to use number, like **1, 2, 3, 4...** How to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override some templates in your theme. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2012/03/30/overriding-the-pager-rendering-in-orchard.aspx for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient and detailed answer. I think I should ask search engine for help before ask question here. Thank you very much!